# Java stream iterating over a list most efficient way

Tags: java, iterator, java-stream

Given a

```
 List<User> listUser; //Userobject contains fields userName,userId, forName, last Name
```

is it possible instead of writing 5 lines to output the user field values

```
listUser.get(0).getUserName
listUser.get(0).getUserId
listUser.get(0).getforName and so on
```

so the output should be

```
userName -> Hans
userId -> 1
forName -> foo
lastName -> bar
```

just in one line of code and not having to write 5 lines? i.e by stream or something?

```
listUser.stream().map(s->s.getUserName) //same as above?
```

Comment: Are you trying to print the whole object? Do you have a toString method?

Comment: Just use `for (User user: listUser)`. That will only traverse the list once, and you can print each property inside the loop body.

Comment: There is no iteration here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to write a `toString` method for the class that has the five lines of code:

```
public String toString() {
    return "User name: " + getUserName() + "\n" +
           "User ID: " + getUserID() + "\n" +
           "Form name: " + getFormName() + "\n" +
           //...
           ;
}
```

And then in the `Stream` you can simply do:

```
listUser.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: yes i think it is best solution even if i have to write 5 lines so no other way but thanks  ;)

Comment: @MicroLova you can further explore Lombok for cutting short the boiler plate further and use the annotation `@ToString`.